# Can I create a 1 byte local variable?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I want to create a 1 byte local variable in my function, so can I do that or I have to create an extra 3 bytes to align the stack?

Comment: create whatever you want, but yes, you'd need to keep the stack aligned.

Comment: @Marc B Does aligning the stack is done with a simple `sub esp, 3`?

Comment: if your code is calling your code then you might not need to align the stack, up to you, although unwise for performance I dont know that generally x86 requires an aligned stack...maybe someone can correct me on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not strictly required to keep the stack aligned, but that depends on what you are actually doing. If you have it just in your code it might be ok. If you call operating system functions it might have side effects. For example, I once got a strange error in Windows `CreateFile` which was because of a missaligned stack, and the errormessage was totally missleading. Took me quite some time until I figured out what was wrong.

The architecture itself doesn't require it though.

Comment: Does the stack alignment always needs to be to a 4 bytes boundary, or does it depends on the calling convention of a function? I have also read that SSE requires a 16 bytes stack alignment.

Comment: It depends on the requirements in question, so this can not be answered in a generic way.